# Why is "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" thrown when accessing a arraylist that is populated?

Tags: java, exception

Here is my main class:

```
package main;

public class Main_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game_Map_Handler GMH = new Game_Map_Handler();
        GMH.AddData("adad");
        System.out.println(GMH.RetrieveData());
    }
}
```

Here is another class I have (Game_Map_Handler):

```
package main;
import java.util.*;

public class Game_Map_Handler {
public List<String> Map_Data = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public void AddData(String InData) {
    List<String> Map_Data = new ArrayList<String>();    
    Map_Data.add(InData);
}

public String RetrieveData() {
    String To_Return = Map_Data.get(0);
    return To_Return;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at main.Game_Map_Handler.RetrieveData(Game_Map_Handler.java:13)
at main.Main_Class.main(Main_Class.java:7)
```

---

**Why is this error occurring?** It seems to say that there is nothing populated in "Map_Data", however *I did* populate it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your `Map_Data` variable, in your `AddData` method.

```
public void AddData(String InData) {
    List<String> Map_Data = new ArrayList<String>();   //<-- remove this line 
    Map_Data.add(InData);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public void AddData(String InData) {
    List<String> Map_Data = new ArrayList<String>(); <----
    Map_Data.add(InData);
};
```

Here you are creating a new list and not adding the instance member. And while getting back you are getting from instance member.

Just change that method to

```
public void AddData(String InData) {

    Map_Data.add(InData);
}
```

As a side note , please follow java naming conventions that variable name should be starts with lower case letter, i.e it should be `map_Data`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `this` operator

```
this.Map_Data.add(InData);
```

In your function you are using your local declared list and not the one from the class.